# werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError when click button

Tags: python, flask

I create flask app, and create page with 2 buttons:

```
<form method="post">
    <button id="clearChoices" type="submit" name="clear" value="yes"> Clear my choices</button>
    <button id="NewMeeting" type="submit" name="meeting" value="yes"> New Meeting</button>
</form>
```

in the app.py I get the post request by the function:

```
@app.route("/favorites/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def favorites():
    username = get_user_logged_in()
    if username:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            details = request.form
            clear_but = details['clear']
            meeting_but = details['meeting']
            if clear_but == 'yes':
                clearChoices(username)
                return redirect('/homepage')
            if meeting_but == 'yes':
                return redirect('/new_meeting')
        return render_template('favorites.html', dogs=dogs)
    return redirect('/login')
```

but when I click on Clear my choices I get an error:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'meeting'
```

but when I click on New Meeting I get an error:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'clear'
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: when you say: ```details = request.form```, add a print statement and check what the value of the ```details``` is, and please share it here

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">
    <button id="clearChoices" type="submit" name="clear" value="yes"> Clear my choices</button>
    <button id="NewMeeting" type="submit" name="meeting" value="yes"> New Meeting</button>
</form>
```

From this page, if you click a button, only that data will pass via post method. So if you click "Clear my choices" button, only that data will be sent to the next page. Like this, {'clear' : 'yes'}. And in your flask code, you have this 2 lines, clear_but = details['clear'] and meeting_but = details['meeting']. If you're clicking 1st button, it will through keyError : meeting, for 2nd button the error will be keyError : clear.